# How do I output a matrix from a custom function with a name based on the name of the input matrix

Tags: r

I have a repetitive region of R-script that manipulates matrices that I would like to simplify with a custom function.  I can generate the custom function just fine, but I would like the output of the function to be a matrix in the global environment with a name based on the name of the input matrix.

So the code goes something like this:

```
CustomFunction <- function (input) {
input_mod <- input *2
}
```

(Obviously I have simplified the function here as the actual steps in the function don't matter for the question.)

But what I would like is for the output to be a matrix in the global environment with a name based on the input name.  Then if I run the custom function three times on three different input matrices:  input1, input2 and input3, the output from the custom function should be three matrices in the global environment named input1_mod, input2_mod and input3_mod.

My current abilities in R only lead me to be able to generate an output that always has the same name and I want to be able to run the function many times and store each of the output matrices for subsequent further manipulations.

Thanks for looking and hope you can help!

Comment: Note this is usually not a good thing to do. Better to store thing in lists where you can get them as `input[[1]]` and `input[[2]]` and then you can do `i=4; input[[i]]` for any `i` value. Then your output is a list called `input_mod` and you can loop over `input_mod[[i]]`. Creating things by constructing names and assigning them is clunky and should be avoided.

Comment: Hi Spacedman, this looks like it might be the answer for me.  I'm going to give it a go.

Comment: Hi Spacedman, this is the approach I am taking.  Lists are making my code simpler (well, shorter), although requiring some unlist commands to run the analyses.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the assign function, ex.

`assign("Global.res", x^2, envir = .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: Great, thanks.  For now this is going to be my backup plan if generating lists becomes too time-consuming for me.